# Accessing Vuex submodules inner state with the $store object

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Users from './modules/Users'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        foo: false,
    },
    modules: {
        Users
    },
})
```

and a Users.js:

```
// initial state
const state = {
    users: [],
}
export default {
    state
}
```

From my components, I'm accessing the `Users` store like this:

```
this.$store.state.Users.users.forEach((el) => {}
```

But I don't understand why I have to call `this.$store.state.Users` instead of `this.$store.Users`

I mean, the module `Users` hasn't been defined within the state of the store right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**explanation:**

`this.store.state.Users.users`

- The first `Users` property accessor represented the name of your module.
- The second `users` property represent the inner Object Property of
  the state of the `Users` module

If you want to call `this.$store.state.Users` instead of `this.store.state.Users.users` to get access to your array of users, define `Users.js` in a slightly different way.

See the code:

**Users.js**

```
// initial state
const state = []
export default {
    state
}
```

now the state is flat. so there is no need for extra data accessor.

## Second Better Option

Use [getters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html).

see the code for the second options:

```
const state = {
  users: []
}
const getters = {
  getUsers(state) {
    return state.users
  }
}

export default {
 state,
 getters
}
```

now you can just write: `$this.store.getters['getUsers']`

probably with your `namespaced:true` it will take a little more effort than this. research it.

## EDIT 1

`this.$store` is an object. it contains `mutations` , `getters`, methods like `dispatch` and more. one of the properties of this object, is the `state` itself. so if you want to access the state directly from the `$store` object, you obviously have to access it directly:  `this.$store.state ...`

`this.$store.Users.state` this is not happening. the vuex engine doesn't add another `state` property for each module.

go for the second better options - [getters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html). it's the best practice.

Comment: Thank you, but I was wondering why there has be a `state` between store and Users: `this.$store.state.Users`. I expected that everything in `this.$store.state` belongs to the state of the main datastore, while `this.$store.Users.state` would be the state of the users-store.